# Simple Geocoding Map in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

How do I make a simple map in Jquery that plots only one location.  Here is the code I have now. this plots an array of locations, but I just need a simple map that will plot one point in Lng,Lat format.  I am using the google geocoder for this.

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var markersArray = [];
var bounds;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: ''
});


function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 2,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        navigationControlOptions: {
            style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.SMALL
        }
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': '5th Avenus New Yort'
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });

            bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);

            markersArray.push(marker);
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }
    });

    plotMarkers();
}

var locationsArray = [
    ['Google Official', '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, USA'],
    ['Google 1', '112 S. Main St., Ann Arbor, USA'],
    ['Google 2', '10 10th Street NE, Suite 600 USA']
];

function plotMarkers() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < locationsArray.length; i++) {
        codeAddresses(locationsArray[i]);
    }
}

function codeAddresses(address) {
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address[1]
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.setContent(address[0]);
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });

            bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);

            markersArray.push(marker);
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }

        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I then call this in my file with:

```
<body>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 700px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

I need the new map to plot one lat and lng point along with posting the listing the location in the textbook as above.  I can not figure out how to do this without an array.

Comment: I would start with the [google example for a single marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) and work up from that (: There's no need to use JQuery as such.

Comment: Dom,  This works perfectly for what I need to do but how do I show the  location upon onclick of the icon?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're using an example that shows multiple markers.

I haven't tested it, but I think this JavaScript is close:

```
var geocoder;
var map;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: latlng
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': '5th Avenue New York' }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          position: results[0].geometry.location
      });
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Review this for more information: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding